# In Flutter, I'm having a problem getting images from the internet

Tags: flutter, image, dart

```
    class Question {
  final String question;
  final Image imageName;
  final Answer correctAnswer;

  Question(
      {required this.question,
      required this.imageName,
      required this.correctAnswer});
}
```

I created a class called Question and added the features I want to use in it.

```
class QuestionResult {
  static List<QuestionResult> defaultQuestions = [
    QuestionResult(
        question: Question(
            question:
                "Some Question",
            correctAnswer: Answer.yes,
            imageName: Image.network(
                'https://images.pexels.com/photos/288093/pexels-photo-288093.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1'))),
}
```

Then I show the user a question on the screen and have him answer it. I also take the background image of this question from the internet.

```
  final List<QuestionResult> _questions =
  QuestionResult.getRandomDefaultQuestionsShuffled();

  int _currentQuestionIndex = 0;

 image: AssetImage(
              "${widget._questions.elementAt(_currentQuestionIndex).question.imageName}"),
```

On the page where I want to show the questions and images, I am trying to get the images that I have assigned to the questions with such a code.

I took the images to be shown to the user as Image.Network(). Here, however, I could not establish that connection and tried to call it with AssetImage(). Of course, it didn't show the images because it couldn't find any asset folder. How can I establish the Image.network connection here?

Comment: Use NetworkImage instead of AssetImage

Comment: I no longer get errors but images are not showing. The background is in white color.

Comment: Can you show us the full widget :D

Comment: Just curious: why don't you just store the URL in your class and call on it directly within the widget you want to show it in? Less likelihood of messing something up if you handle it in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

For images that get from the internet you can use `NetworkImage` instead of `AssetImage`

like this:

```
image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage('www.google.com'),),
```